# Оптимизация кода

Tags: php, оптимизация

Вот код, который накодил я:

Подскажите, **как это можно оптимизировать?** Ничего в череп не лезет.

--Тут были нехорошие слова =)--

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++)
{
    $ch_st[$i] = false;
}
switch ($_SESSION['u_id'])
{
    case $data['worker_id']:
        if ($data['sys_id'] == 1)
        {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= 9; $i++)
            {
                print '<option value="' . $status[$i]['id'] . '" >' . $status[$i]['name'] . '</option>';
                $ch_st[$i] = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            print '<option value="' . $status[3]['id'] . '" >' . $status[3]['name'] . '</option>';
            print '<option value="' . $status[5]['id'] . '" >' . $status[5]['name'] . '</option>';
            print '<option value="' . $status[7]['id'] . '" >' . $status[7]['name'] . '</option>';
            print '<option value="' . $status[9]['id'] . '" >' . $status[9]['name'] . '</option>';
            $ch_st[3] = true;
            $ch_st[5] = true;
            $ch_st[7] = true;
            $ch_st[9] = true;
        }

    case $data['creator_id']:
        if ($data['sys_id'] == 1)
        {
            print !$ch_st[1] ? '<option value="' . $status[1]['id'] . '" >' . $status[1]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
            print !$ch_st[6] ? '<option value="' . $status[6]['id'] . '" >' . $status[6]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
            print !$ch_st[9] ? '<option value="' . $status[9]['id'] . '" >' . $status[9]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
            $ch_st[1] = true;
            $ch_st[6] = true;
            $ch_st[9] = true;
        }

    case $data['manager_id']:
        if ($data['sys_id'] == 1)
        {
            print !$ch_st[8] ? '<option value="' . $status[8]['id'] . '" >' . $status[8]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
            print !$ch_st[5] ? '<option value="' . $status[5]['id'] . '" >' . $status[5]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
            print !$ch_st[2] ? '<option value="' . $status[2]['id'] . '" >' . $status[2]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
        }
        else
        {
            print !$ch_st[9] ? '<option value="' . $status[9]['id'] . '" >' . $status[9]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
        }
}
```

ver 4:

```
    $acc_groups = array(//groups
    0 => array(1 => range (1, 9),2 => array(3, 5, 7, 9),3 => array(3, 5, 7, 9),4 => array(3, 5, 7, 9)),
    1 => array(1 => array(1, 6, 9),2 => array(),3 => array(),4 => array()),
    2 => array(1 => array(2, 5, 8),2 => array(9),3 => array(9),4 => array(9))
);
foreach ($cow as $k => $v)
{
    $user[$v['id']]['acc'][] = 0;
}
$user[$data['worker_id']]['acc'][] = 0;
$user[$data['manager_id']]['acc'][] = 1;
$user[$data['creator_id']]['acc'][] = 2;

if (isset ($user[$_SESSION['u_id']]))
{
    #sample code
    $ch_st = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count ($user[$_SESSION['u_id']]['acc']); $i++)
    {
        $n = $user[$_SESSION['u_id']]['acc'][$i];
        $i1 = 0;
        while ($n1 = $acc_groups[$i][$data['sys_id']][$i1++])
        {
            print isset ($ch_st[$n1]) ? '' : '<option value="' . $status[$n1]['id'] . '" >' . $status[$n1]['name'] . '</option>' ;
            $ch_st[$n1] = true;
        }
    }
    #sample code
}
```

Comment: Вы что нибудь слышали о циклах?

Comment: а также о таких новейших изобретениях программистской мысли, как функции, массивы и ассоциативные массивы

Comment: по скорости оптимизировать, только print на echo заменить :) а код красивше можно написать. Тут даже думать не надо, циклы, массивы и прочее. Не надо делать такие выпады, если вы просите помощи, то будьте попроще.

Comment: Циклы - используются где это имеет смысл.

@DreamChild, воспользуйтесь зрением. Функция бесполезна, а массивы явно настолько незаметны, да?

Вот что у людей за желание обосрать не самое плохое решение задачи, даже не ознакомившись с ним?

Если вы так круты, и этот код для вас смешон, давайте, сделайте лучше!

Comment: вас сильно смутит заявление, что тут просится массив типа (буду js рисовать, т.к. он лаконичнее)

    {
     'worker_id':[['*'],[3,5,7,9]], //тут вместо * можно даже 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 написать
     'creator_id': [[1,6,9]],[],
     'manager_id':[[8,5,2],[9]
    };

?
и у вас видимо ошибка в последнем случае: для manager $ch_st не задаются почему-то. если это не ошибка, то можно легко сделать исключение одним условием

Comment: $ch_st это "галочка" чтобы не было повторных выводов если человек является хоть всеми тремя лицами одновременно.

Для первого пункта свича он не проверяется, для последнего не имеет смысла присваивать.

Изменения в течении нескольких минут слишком логичны, посему решил не уведомлять. 
См. Версию 2, которая чуть лаконичнее, но всё равно сама логика не очень.

Comment: @Rijen, это все можно свернуть до одного цикла и условия, логика не очень, потому-что структура ущербная. если хотите нормально зарефакторить поищите шаблоны ACL и выберите подходящий. чтобы не повторялось, лучше соберите массив доступных опций и потом циклом одним напечатайте (заодно отсортировать можно).

Comment: @Rijen еще раз говорю (и не только я) - решение тут напрашивается такое: создать функцию и определить логику выбора элементов массива через ассоциативный массив. В этом случае код может сократиться в несколько раз

Comment: что вам этот while так нравится ? :) 

    foreach чем плох ?

и в массиве $acc_groups можно данные не дублировать, сделайте

    $acc_groups = array(
        array(range (1, 9),array(3, 5, 7, 9)),
        array(array(1, 6, 9),array()),
        array(array(2, 5, 8),array(9))
    );

и выбирайте примерно так: 

     foreach ($acc_groups[$i][$data['sys_id']===1?0:1] as $n1)

Comment: @eicto, На дублирование данных есть причина. Тем более что в боевых условиях данные выгружаются из БД, и на любом уровне ограничены только форматом данных.



while звучит приятнее =)
А на самом деле, если я правильно выучился, то foreach имеет плюшку (именуемую оптимизацией для работы с массивами и объектами), которая позволяет возвращать ключи. while такой плюшки не имеет. Теоретически мы экономим горстку тактов юзая while, но в код пыха я не смотрел, по сему не ручаюсь =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[Потыкать можно тут](http://ideone.com/780R9B)**

Входные данные:

```
<?php
# Какие типы могут быть?
$user_groups = array('worker_id', 'creator_id', 'manager_id');
# Выбор пользователей по типу и условию
$users = array(
    # group
    'worker_id' => array(
        # selection
        'sys_id_eq_1' => range(1, 9),
        'default' => range(3, 9, 2)
    ),
    # group
    'creator_id' => array(
        # selection
        'sys_id_eq_1' => array(1, 6, 9),
        'default' => array()
    ),
    # group
    'manager_id' => array(
        # selection
        'sys_id_eq_1' => array(2, 5, 8),
        'default' => array(9)
    )
);
# Имитация входных данных. Например, показать creator и manager
$data = array(
    'sys_id' => 1,
    'worker_id' => 34,
    'creator_id' => 45,
    'manager_id' => 45
);

# Тут, похоже, у ТС пользователи...
$status = array(
    1 => array('id' => 221, 'name' => 'Вася'),
    2 => array('id' => 222, 'name' => 'Петя'),
    3 => array('id' => 223, 'name' => 'Леша'),
    4 => array('id' => 224, 'name' => 'Костя'),
    5 => array('id' => 225, 'name' => 'Настя'),
    6 => array('id' => 226, 'name' => 'Маша'),
    7 => array('id' => 227, 'name' => 'Даша'),
    8 => array('id' => 228, 'name' => 'Саша'),
    9 => array('id' => 229, 'name' => 'Женя')
);

$u_id = 34;  # $_SESSION['u_id'];
```

---

Сам вывод:

```
$output = '<select>';

foreach ($user_groups as $group) {
    $is_current_user_in_group = $u_id === $data[$group];
    if ($is_current_user_in_group) {
        $selection = ($data['sys_id'] == 1) ? 'sys_id_eq_1' : 'default';
        foreach ($users[$group][$selection] as $user) {
            $id = $status[$user]['id'];
            $name = $status[$user]['name'];
            $text = "<option value='{$id}'>{$name} - {$user}</option>";
            # Чтобы исключить дублирование
            $output .= (!!strpos($output, $text)) ? '' : $text;
        }
    }
}
$output .= '</select>';
echo $output;
```

Comment: Не, статус, это статус задачи в данном контексте, которые доступны воркеру, коворкерам, создателю и мэнеджеру

Answer (score 6):

Рекомендую сделать отдельную функцию для печати и вынести туда две такие строки

```
print !$ch_st[$n] ? '<option value="' . $status[$n]['id'] . '" >' . $status[$n]['name'] . '</option>' : '';
$ch_st[$n] = true;
```

там ещё есть вызовы print, но думаю, им можно либо отдельной фунцией, либо к этой привести.

После этого код будет выглядеть более "стройно".

Comment: А присваивание $ch_st будет корректно?
function(array $ast, array $status, array $ch_st)
//содержимое

$ch_st = function(....,$ch_st)?

Comment: @Rijen, сделайте ссылку

    function myFunct($n,&$status,&$ch_st);

Comment: @eicto, Спасибо. Обидно когда только обсирают, не предлагая конструктивных решений. 

Я тоже извиняюсь за выброс чернового наброска, долго думали где что должно быть, я думал что будет проще и начал писать так, не исправив элементарные вещи. 

(В первом пункте изначально было не все 9, а только 4, поэтому там не было цикла. Так же ещё раньше было только 2 элемента а не 9)

На счет использования массива, попробую сейчас построить логику. Пока слабо представляю как, учитывая динамичную генерацию id для сверки.

Comment: Дамс, в итоговом варианте функция оказалась бесполезной.